# Sharing internet from android to PC over LAN

Tags: tethering, wifi-tethering, usb-tethering, lan

Is it possible to share my mobile connection with a PC over a LAN cable?

Anyway, My scheme is OTG micro USB and then OTG USB ethernet adapter and then LAN cable to Windows (Bootcamp Mac).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By LAN you mean WLAN or intend to use an OTG Ethernet adapter?

Comment: Use OTG Ethernet adapter

Comment: so did you try and it didn't work?

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)